# I set my RDS (psql) db to NOT publicly accessible and now I cannot connect to my db using pgAdmin. How can I connect to it now?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-rds

I am using elastic beanstalk and I have my REST application running there.  This REST API application can access my RDS postgres database, and my RDS is only accessible in my VPC.  I have updated my VPC settings, so my REST API does seem to work, since I have some endpoints I'm hitting to insert, and I can also make requests to pull the most recent data, etc.

However... I can't tell for sure!

I was using PgAdmin to connect to my database, but since changing the RDS instance's publicly accessible setting to NO, I can no longer connect to it from my macbook.  Is there a way I can still connect to that database using PgAdmin or psql, perhaps by using SSH or something?

From my reading it seems I cannot SSH to RDS directly, so I am not sure how to proceed.  Thank you!

Comment: REST Application is running in EC2 Instance. Correct?

Answer (score 2):

Choosing the option YES for publicly accessible for your DB instance will give your instance a public IP address.

Is your RDS in private subnets ?

If yes, I've had that issue before. What I did in my case was to setup an openVPN server and have the client on my mac. But that solution was driven by having not only RDS in the private subnets but other services so we could access them through the VPN connection.

As for OpenVPN, I have made a blog post for it: [here](http://blog.kaliloudiaby.com/index.php/set-up-and-configure-openvpn-on-centos-7/)

Answer (score 0):

From your question as much I can understand you need to access your DB from public outside amazon VPC

just modify the DB instance

open rds dashboard select your DB instance you want to modify

top instance action >> Modify >> change the Publicly available option to yes.
image reference:
[image]

change your Db security group port to anywhere or your Ip.(so at least you can only access)

Now you can access your DB from your MacBook

Comment: Well, the whole point I made it publicly accessible NO is so that it will only be available to my VPC applications.

Comment: If there's a way to SSH to my VPC, how do I do that for my RDS instance?

Comment: @scarywolfman there is no way you can ssh to RDS as you don't have access to the RDS OSlevel though you can get the ssh to any EC2 instance if you wan to.

From you EC2  you can install PostgreSQL-client or pg admin and connect to DB , also your DB will be still inside you vpc without public access

Comment: Thanks!  I guess since I can connect to my EC2, I will figure out how to install the psql client.  I am not able to use `apt` so I'll have to figure out my OS and everything.  Unless you know how to do that.  I just deployed my express application using the express preset using `eb-cli`